# HELP How to integrate my online exam in joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6

I've been created an online exam written in php and i just wanted to integrate that into my website created by Joomla 1.6.
One of my problem is, how to transfer my online exam code into Joomla 1.6 and how connect the database of Online exam into Joomla.

I appreciate all the help.

Thank you and God bless.

Comment: This really can not be answered - we do not know how your online exam is built. My best advice is that you start into how Joomla components are built: [Developing a Model-View-Controller (MVC) Component for Joomla!1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!1.6_-_Part_01)

Answer (score 1):

Well, Chronoforms V4 is a great tool to for forms and such.
It allows you to specify tables to attach the forms to, and allows for custom elements and things of that nature, but also allows completely custom forms (i.e. your entire PHP form/exam).

So while I'm not 100% sure how your exam works, I would put a strong suggestion out there that Chronoforms could work around it.  Multi-page forms, all sorts of tricks/tweaks are out their for Chronoforms and their forums are constantly looked at by the main programmer and some GREAT help.

I'd look there first.